# Is "find_all" and "select" the same thing?

Tags: ruby

These two statements give me the same results:

```
[1,2,3,4].find_all { |x| x.even? }

[1,2,3,4].select{ |x| x.even? }
```

Is `find_all` just an alias? Is there a reason to use one over another?

Comment: This question has accepted the wrong answer.

Answer (score 69):

`#find_all` and `#select` are very similar; the difference is very subtle. In most of the cases, they are equivalent. It depends on the class implementing it.

`Enumerable#find_all` and `Enumerable#select` run on the same code.

The same happens for `Array` and `Range`, as they use `Enumerable` implementation.

In the case of `Hash`, `#select` is redefined to return a Hash instead of an Array, but `#find_all` is inherited from `Enumerable`

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
h = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6}

a.select{|x| x.even?}       # => [2, 4, 6]
a.find_all{|x| x.even?}     # => [2, 4, 6]

h.select{|k,v| v.even?}     # => {:b=>2, :d=>4, :f=>6}
h.find_all{|k,v| v.even?}   # => [[:b, 2], [:d, 4], [:f, 6]]
```

Answer (score 16):

[`Enumerable#find_all`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all) *Returns an array containing all elements of enum for which the given block returns a true value*, which is not the case for `select`. `Enumerable#select` returns the `Array`, if the receiver on which you are calling `#select` method, don't have it's own `#select` method. Otherwise on which receiver you are calling `#select` method, it will return similar type of receiver, after processing the block condition.

Like [`Hash#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-select) *Returns a new hash consisting of entries for which the block returns `true`* and [`Array#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-select) *Returns a new array containing all elements of ary for which the given block returns a true value.* Now `Range#select` will give you return back an `Array`, as `Range` class don't have its own instance method called `#select`. Rather being an `Enumerable`,it will call [`Enumerable#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select).

```
rng = (1..4)
ary = [1,2]
hsh = {:a => 1}

rng.method(:select) # => #<Method: Range(Enumerable)#select>
hsh.method(:select) # => #<Method: Hash#select>
ary.method(:select) # => #<Method: Array#select>
```

Here is a full demonstration with example in-favor of my explanation above :

```
hsh = {:a => 2, :b => 3 }
ary = [1,2,3]
rng = (1..3)

# Look find_all always gives Array.
hsh.find_all{ true } # => [[:a, 2], [:b, 3]]
ary.find_all{ true } # => [1, 2, 3]
rng.find_all{ true } # => [1, 2, 3]

# Look select not giving Array always, explanation of why so is written
# above in my answer.
hsh.select{ true } # => {:a=>2, :b=>3}
ary.select{ true } # => [1, 2, 3]
rng.select{ true } # => [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Check the documentation you linked to -- both have identical descriptions, and both return arrays for the given block.

Comment: @DylanMarkow I don't agree, You recheck it.

Comment: I thinks you should provide an example showing that, in general, `select` and `find_all` don't behave the same.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, for Arrays, they return identical results. For other things (e.g. Hashes), they may return different things.

According to the Enumerable documentation for [select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) and [find_all](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all), both methods point to the same source code, and both return either an Array (if a block is given) or an Enumerator (if no block is given).

While the Array class implements its own version of `select` (but lets Enumerable handle `find_all`), they still do the same thing.

Comment: -1 for saying *Yes, they return identical results* It is not like that.

Comment: For his example, an array, they do return identical results. The code used to get there may be slightly different, but there is no case where, given the same array, the two methods won't return the same thing.

Comment: OP asked *Is find_all and select the same thing in ruby?*.. OP probably took Array as an example. But OP asked it overall..

Comment: *Enumerable (if no block is given)* is also wrong.. It is an *Enumerator*, not `Enumerable`.

Comment: Sorry, Enumerable was a typo.

Answer (score -1):

### #**find_all**

with array it returns result as array

with hash it returns result as array

---

### **select**

with array it returns result as array

with hash it returns result as hash

---

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).